# Executing arbitrary C# code in WiX

Tags: c#, installation, wix

I want to run some arbitrary code in a WiX installer and have the results of that available as early on as is possible.

To test this, I am using the return value to set a label field. It doesn't seem to work. I can get it to run when I put a

```
<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CustomAction1">1</Publish>
```

inside the control for a next button, but this is too 'late'. I want that code executed right at the start.

Here is what I tried:

```
<Binary Id="WixCustomActions" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)$(var.CAProjectName)\bin\Release\$(var.CAProjectName).CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="CustomAction1" BinaryKey="WixCustomActions" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait"/> (tried many combinations here)`
```

Later on.....

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="CustomAction1" After="InstallInitialize">1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

on paper this should work.

I know it isn't a problem with the custom action itself, because when placed on the next key, I get the desired result.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The InstallExecuteSequence table lists actions that are executed when the top-level INSTALL action is executed. Try using LaunchConditions on InstallUISequence

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed it to InstallUISequence and used <Custom Action="CustomAction1" After="CostFinalize">1</Custom> but this errors with "DEBUG: Error 2762:  Unable to schedule operation. The action must be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize." but this doesn't compiled with "Error 1 Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixAction:InstallUISequence/InstallFinalize' in section 'Product:{5A997B05-4696-4C8F-BAA8-6915B8AB6FC5}'."

Comment: Where your custom action code exist, is it in Install method or beforeInstall. Explain scenerio why u want to do, then I will be able to give the better solution

Comment: Essentially I want to run some that can be used *by* the installer to populate fields and in some cases make decisions based on IP addresses etc. so it is key that this code is run as soon as the installer is instantiated.

Comment: And if this should happen only when user begins to install, right? Then write your code in Install method and call on installsequence itself. If not, then use launcecondition to check resources on system

Comment: I want this to happen the moment the user runs the .exe so that the results of the custom code can be used to alter the install 'experience'. so not when they finally press 'install' before then.

Comment: Then you need to go two installer approach, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="Your_Custom_Action"
          After="CostFinalize"
          Overridable="yes">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

This code launches 'Your_Custom_Action' at the very begining of the installation.